# Accessing the WebSQL database created by a WebView

Tags: android, sqlite, android-webview, web-sql

We are assembling an Android app around an existing web-based solution by using an Android WebView. The solution makes use of WebSQL to store data, which we would like to pull out and use in our app.

Is there any way to access, in an Android service, the underlying SQLite database that is created by a WebView? Or is there any other method we can use to get at the data that has been saved by the web page?